# Vue - передача атрибута в компонент с таким же названием как и свойство

Tags: javascript, шаблоны, vue.js, компоненты

Есть компонент с условным свойством "test", в которое передаётся некоторое значение. Также требуется задать "test" атрибут компонента, как это можно сделать?

**Пример компонента**

```
<template>
    <div <!-- сюда нужно подставить атрибут "test" с переданным значением -->>
        <!-- вывод значения свойства "test" -->
        {{ test }}
    </div>  
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            type: {
                type: String,
                default: "..."
            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Пример вызова компонента с передачей свойства "test"**

```
<v-my-component test="ds"></v-my-component>
```

**Если же свойство "test" не будет указано в самом компоненте**

```
<template>
    <div <!-- сюда установится атрибут "test" с переданным значением -->> 
    </div>  
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

**Получится**

```
<div test="ds">
</div>
```

P.S. на данный момент не вижу другого выхода как использовать префиксы у свойств, но такой вариант не нравится.

По просьбе из комментария добавлю результат, который должен появиться в итоге:

```
<template>
<div test="Значение атрибута">

    <!-- Значение свойства --> 
    {{ test }}
</div>  
</template>

// вызов примерно такой должен быть, параметры "prop:test" и "attr:test" выдумал для примера
<v-my-component prop:test="Значение свойства" attr:test="Значение атрибута"></v-my-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто добавить v-bind атрибут на корень компонента:

```js
Vue.component("test", {
  props: ["test"],
  template: '<div :test="test">I\'m a component</div>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myValue: "aaa"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <test :test="myValue"></test>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем так, что если свойство test используется в дочернем div, а атрибут test нужно задать в родительском div?

Comment: не совсем понимаю, можно пример того, что хочется получить в конце?

Comment: добавил к задаче